# weird jQuery / JavaScript bug ot triggering script

Tags: javascript

I have a colorbox modal window with a form. if i click to post the form which is an ajax request it sends the data and then returns with new html that overwrites the modals  html.

ive got the exact same code for 'adding' with just a few minor differences for the edit (edit sends the id). it all visually works fine and the data is saved etc but on the page for both edit and add is a script tag that executes to highlight the input fields that have validation errors. for add it works but for editing it does not trigger the js code in the script tag it is almost like the script tag is not there yet i can see it in the html with firebug. i can copy the code into the console and run it and it works. there are no errors. i tried replacing the code with a simple console.log() but that does not fire either.

one thing is tha if i use jQuery 1.8 it works but with jQuery 1.10 it does not but ive stepped through all the code and i cannot see any errors plus ive run it with the migrate plugin and i see nothing when click the buttons for the editing of the item.

any idea on why it is not triggering the js ?

Here is the code:

ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type:ajaxType,
                    url:url,
                    data:$("#addEditAddressForm").serialize(),
                    success:function (response) {
                        if (ajaxType == "POST") {
                            $("#colorbox .content").html(response);
                            $("#selectedAddress").show();
                            if ($(response).find(".globalAlert").hasClass('grey')) {
                                $('.addAddressSection').removeClass('noDisplay');
                                $('.addressList, .buttonsContainer').hide();
                            }
                            else {
                                $('.addAddressSection').addClass('noDisplay');
                                $('.addressList, .buttonsContainer').show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            $("#colorbox .content").html(response);
                            $('.addAddressSection').removeClass('noDisplay');
                            if ($('.addEditAddressForm').hasClass('noDisplay')) {
                                $('.addressList, .buttonsContainer').show();
                            }
                            else {
                                $('.addressList, .buttonsContainer').hide();
                            }
                        }
                        $.colorbox.resize();

                    }
                });
```

Ajax is working fine

here is the html:

```
<div class="addEditContactSection noDisplay">
    #if($!editMode)
        <h2>Edit Contact</h2>
    #else
        <h2>Add Contact</h2>
    #end
    #errorMessages($errors)
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8"  action="addContact" method="post" id="addEditContactForm">
        <input type="hidden" value="$!contact.id" name="id" id="id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="$!custId" name="custId" id="custId" />
        <fieldset class="internal">
            #if($!editMode)
                <legend>$!contact.firstName $!contact.lastName</legend>
            #else
                <legend>Contact Details</legend>
            #end
            <dl>
                <dt class="clear">
                    <label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" value="$!contact.firstName" name="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="40"/>
                </dd>
                <dt class="clear">
                    <label for="lastName">Last Name*</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" value="$!contact.lastName" name="lastName" id="lastName" maxlength="40"/>
                </dd>
                <dt class="clear">
                    <label for="email">Email*</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" value="$!contact.email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="70"/>
                </dd>
                <dt class="clear">
                    <label for="telephone">Telephone*</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" value="$!contact.telephone" name="telephone" id="telephone" />
                </dd>
                <dt class="clear">
                    <label for="mobileTelephone">Mobile Phone</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" value="$!contact.mobileTelephone" name="mobileTelephone" id="mobileTelephone" />
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <div class="contactButtons">
               <input id="saveContact" type="submit" value="Save Contact" name="saveContact"  class="overLayContactLink submitButton #if($!editMode)editContact#else addContactNew #end submitFormLight"/>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the script on page which works for one and not the other

> $(document).ready(function() {
>               var errorFields = "$!fieldNames";
>               var i;
>               var fieldsArr = errorFields.split(",");
>
> ```
>         for (i = 0; i <= fieldsArr.length - 1; i++) {
>             $("#" + fieldsArr[i]).addClass("error");
>             $("#" + fieldsArr[i]).parent().prev().children("label").addClass("labelError");
>         }
>     })
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Please add code, hard to guess where the problem could be if we don't see the code.

Comment: No idea because **you did not post any code**.

Comment: I count 527 different reasons this could be happening. Seriously, post your code.

Comment: it is not jQuery not firing, if i put an alert or console.log into the script tags nothing shows - ive added my code as best as i can now

Comment: @Lee Unfortunately, you have to do some debugging. Then you can ask a more specific question like: "in function x, I expected variable y to be 'something' but it's 'something else'". We can't possibly debug the code you posted. If you really want people to help, you create a http://jsfiddle.netjs where we can see the problem in action

Comment: the issue i have here is there is no issue with the code itself i think it is something with the loading of the js code but im not sure what. ive stepped through all the code step by step and there are no errors it simply doesnt fire anything in the script tags even if it is an alert and no other code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging and literally trying everything it was due to where the response code was being put.

I changed this line:

```
$("#colorbox .content").html(response);
```

to be:

```
$("#showContactList").html(response);
```

it was the same div but using the id it worked.
I am not 100% sure why this would make it work but it did and thanks goodness for that!
The only thought i had which is why i looked at this was at some stage i saw 2 divs with the class .content so maybe it was getting the js confused but funny how it worked fine with jQuery 1.8.